# How do I build List or Array Types from a stored runtime Type for the sake of comparing them?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

**NOTE: When I originally asked this question I included IEnumerable. After some responses, I realized it was obvuscating the question because I was mixing interfaces and classes. I've removed it. Now I'm only asking about these three class types:**

- a type that represents a single thing
- a type that represents a list of those things
- a type that represents an array of those things

**Before responding, please make absolutely sure you understand what I'm asking. I am *NOT* asking about:**

- types that derive from another type
- types that are assignable from another type
- types that implement some interface

**Edited question:**

If I have retrieved a type using `typeof()`, can I somehow use that to check for types that represent lists or arrays of the retrieved type?

I want to do this specifically so that I can do comparisons to find out if an unknown type is either some other specific type or a list or array of that specific type.

Here's a code example. Explanation is below the code.

```
public void Example()
{
    Type k = typeof(Kitten);
    Type m = typeof(Whatever); //Could even be a List<Whatever> or Whatever[]

    Compare(k, m);
}


public void Compare(Type someType, Type otherType)
{
     Type ListOfSomeType = ?????;
     Type ArrayOfSomeType = ??????;

     if(otherType == someType)
          //otherType is a Kitten

     elseif(otherType == ListOfSomeType)
          //otherType is a List<Kitten>

     elseif(otherType == ArrayOfSomeType)
          //otherType is a Kitten[]
}
```

The point is that the `Compare` function gets `Type` arguments containing the types. It has no idea what they actually are. But it needs to be able to find out if they are the same type, or if the second one is a TYPE OF list or array storing objects of the first kind of type.

I entered question marks (?????) for the imaginary code I would like to use to construct the collection types.

How can I do this? This question is not hypothetical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can do this with reflection. It's quite straightforward.

You can get the open type for `List<>` and then use `MakeGenericType` for the list. And `Type.MakeArrayType` for the array.

```
public static void Compare(Type someType, Type otherType)
{
    var listOfSomeTypeType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(someType);
    var arrayOfSomeTypeType = someType.MakeArrayType();

    Console.WriteLine("SomeType: {0}",someType.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("OtherType: {0}",otherType.Name);

    if(someType == otherType)
        Console.WriteLine("someType and otherType are the same");
    else if(listOfSomeTypeType == otherType)
        Console.WriteLine("otherType is a list of someType");
    else if(arrayOfSomeTypeType == otherType)
        Console.WriteLine("otherType is an array of someType");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No match found");
}
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/HQH48424

Answer (score 0):

```
Type arrayOfSomeType = someType.MakeArrayType();
Type listOfSomeType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { someType });
```